# Nested data types in Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, delta-lake

The documentation on Parquet files indicates that it can store / handle nested data types.  However, I am unable to find much more information on best practices / pitfalls / ... when storing these nested datatypes to Parquet.

I am considering the following scenario:

1. I am using PySpark (Spark 3.3) to store my Spark DataFrame to a Delta Lake file (which uses Parquet files under the hood).
2. The Spark DataFrame has a nested column of datatype `StructType` in addition to many (100+) "regular" columns with a singular datatype.
3. This nested column will have many sub-columns (100+)

Think something along the lines of

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- topic_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- digit_1: long (nullable = true)
 | ...
```

Questions I have regarding this:

1. Will the nested information be stored as a single column or will I find columns `info.topic_1`, 'info.digit_1`, ...?
2. What about array columns or mapping columns?
3. It seems that a lot of older SO posts indicate that more columns will be read in case a nested columns are present.  Is still a problem for Spark 3?
4. Any best practices of storing these nested datatypes?

[I am aware of the following SO question, but people indicated it was for Spark 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49474814/2931774)

Comment: Can accept answer pls?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about extra columns - columnar is parquet, neither about pushdown for performance.

The nested attributes are each stored as a new column. It's hard to explain, but `definition levels` and  `repetition levels` are key concepts.

Please consult 2 excellent posts:

- https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-parquet/nested-data-representation-parquet/read
- https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet

BTW: not sure why someone felt needs more focus.

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps an odd follow-up question, but what if you would store a mapping column to a Parquet where the datatype of a value at a specific key could change?  Would that still work?

Comment: @bramb pls elaborate with example or new question. Not sure I know the answer. This is what I know http://cloudsqale.com/2020/06/18/how-map-column-is-written-to-parquet-converting-json-to-map-to-increase-read-performance/